# JTextArea Storing Each Line

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextarea

I'm making an Address Book application, and I have the basic fields (name, age, phone numbers, etc.) and I have a JTextArea for placing miscellaneous comments, since I won't know *how much* info I need to add. It could be one line or hundreds.

I want to know if there is a way to store this data and place it back into the field when the contacts information is loaded. I could store the entire JTextArea as a String, but would that keep the correct formatting? Or save many Strings into an ArrayList or something similar.

Additionally, is there a method to save **blocks** of text as opposed to **single lines**? For example. I might want to store an URL, or I might want to store a 5-line poem the contact wrote. Obviously, storing the URL could take one line, but the poem would take 5 lines and therefore 5 Strings.

What seems like a decant storage solution? If my concept doesn't make sense, please comment and I'll try to make it more clear.

Comment: You can format your data into JSON, XML, CSV, ... format and save to text file, then reload it into your fields

Comment: Saving it as a single String should fine, it will, normally, preserve newlines as well. This will of course, depend on where you are storing it

Comment: Personally, your concept isn't very clear. You're making a GUI i presume and displaying extra data in a JTextArea? Are you using the TextArea as a data structure or are you intending to display erroneous information for a reason?

Comment: @leigero You would have basic info (phone#, name, birthday) in their own fields. You then have a large TextArea for misc. comments that don't fit into other fields. Think of it as a giant notepad.

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you please post that in an answer so I can accept it? Just tested it quickly in a sample program and it works perfectly!

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that a string is limited to a single line. It's not. A string could be an entire novel.

Comment: @aaron Done, its a little simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving it as a single String should fine, it will, normally, preserve newlines as well.

This will of course, depend on where you are storing it

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your address book app is asking a user to input simple values as you suggested and I'm assuming it is saving these values into a "Contact" object or something similar.

If this is the case, you can simply add a `String comments;` to the Contacts class and implement a getter and setter method accordingly.

Just get the data from the JTextField and store it into that Contact's comments variable.

```
Contact person = new Contact();
person.setComments(textArea.getText());
```

Something like that. Then you can reference the `person.getComments()` later on and print that back out to the TextField if thats what you want to do with it.